# How to connect field of template with forms.py and with views.py so that values pass in template field can go through functions

Tags: python, django

I am new to django. I making an login and register page using django .In this i have the templates files called login.html.In registration i have given the field of name,email and password .Now my issues is how to connect those values of name field in form.py and views.py.I didn't what to write in form.py and why we use that

I have tried my best to do.But don't know it is correct or not.

login.html

```
<input type ="text" placeholder="name" id="name" name ="name" onblur="name_check(this.value)" style="margin-bottom: 05px;" required />
        <span id="errorname"style="color: red;"></span>
        <input type ="email" placeholder="email id" id="email" name="email" onblur="email_check(this.value)" style="margin-bottom: 05px;" required />
        <span id="erroremail"style="color: red;"></span>
        <input type ="password" placeholder="password"id="password-input-0" name="password" onblur="password_form(this.value)" style="margin-bottom: 05px;" required />
        <span id="errorpassword"style="color: red;"></span>
        <input type ="password" placeholder="confirm password"  id="password-input-1" name="confirm_password" required/>
      <button type="submit" onclick="password_form(); name_check(); email_check();">sign up</button>
        <p style="color:#6F53C3;font-family:cambria;"class="message">Already Registered? <a href="#"> login </a>
```

views.py

```
def StudentRegister(request):
    form_var = form.StudentRegister()

    if(request.method == "POST"):
        form_var = form.StudentRegister(request.POST)

        if(form_var.is_valid()):
            Student_Name1 = request.POST['name']
            Email1 = request.POST['email']
            Password1 = request.POST['password']
            Confirm_PassWord1 = request.POST['confirm_password']

            if(Password1 == Confirm_PassWord1):
                form_var.save(commit = True)

                count = AddEnquiry.objects.filter(Student_Name=Student_Name1).count()

                return render(request,"DashBoard.html",{'count':count})
    return render(request,"login1.html",{'form':form_var})
```

Comment: In your templates write `{{form.as_p}}` it will render a form, go and inspect the inputs to get the `name ` of fields  then simply edit `name` of inputs, like for password you will get `password2` then
`<input type ="password" placeholder="confirm password"  id="id_password2" name="password2" required/>`

Comment: what does StudentRegister look like in your code?

Comment: so @PankajSharma where to type '{{form.as_p}}' <body>
 <div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
  <form class ="register-form" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  <p  style="color:#6F53C3;font-family:cambria;">REGISTER</p>
  <hr width="80%">
   <input type ="text" placeholder="name" id="name" name ="name" onblur="name_check(this.value)" style="margin-bottom: 05px;" required />
   <span id="errorname"style="color: red;"></span>

Comment: In your template i.e `login.html`